# Target lines Javadoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I always write inline comments, until I learnt to use Javadoc. Now I was wondering, how can I effectively select a line and tell something about it in the Javadoc instead of an inline comment.

Example:
This is my void:

```
public void test() {
    //This is a test sentence
    String testSentence = "Test";
    //This is another test sentence
    String anotherTestSentence = "Test";
}
```

How I would do it if there is no other (more effective) method:

```
/**
 * @line 2 This is a test sentence
 * @line 3 This is another test sentence
 */
public void test() {
    String testSentence = "Test";
    String anotherTestSentence = "Test";
}
```

Does anyone know if there is indeed any better way, or that I should use inline comments instead of Javadoc? I noticed that @line did some weird things, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: `@line` isn't a standard javadoc tag. Just out of curiosity where did you come across that?

Comment: I don't know, I just typed it in, targeted the line and that line got some weird marking at the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (at least not with the standard tag set).

First, `@line` is not a standard javadoc tag (see tag list below), and if you used it you would expect to see something along the lines of:

```
sourcefile.java:1234: warning - @line is an unknown tag.
```

Second, from the Oracle docs regarding placement of comments (emphasis mine):

> Documentation comments are recognized only when placed immediately before class, interface, constructor, method, or field declarations -- see the class example, method example, and field example. **Documentation comments placed in the body of a method are ignored.**

So, unfortunately, there is no way to do this. There are no line-related tags, and there is no way to put javadoc comments inside method bodies.

The full syntax of comments as well as a list of supported tags is listed over at [Oracle's `javadoc` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html), in particular:

- [Commenting the Source Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#comments) - Comment syntax.
- [Javadoc Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags) - Full list of supported tags.

(The [Java 8 docs for the tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) are there too, but nothing really changed, I just find the 7 documentation easier to browse.)

Additionally, philosophically, [Kevin Krumwiede hits the nail on the head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634781).

All that said you could probably create your own `@line` tag if you wanted, see the section on `-tag` and `-taglet` command line options [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#tag) (`-taglet` is right below it). Perhaps your previous encounter with `@line` was somebody's custom tag. Custom tag or not, however, you would not be able to put the comments within the method body itself.

Be careful, though... in addition to the philosophical reasons to not do this, you'll also have to take care not to reference absolute line numbers in your documentation (be it a custom tag or just in general), because you will break all of your documentation as soon as you add/remove a line earlier on in the file. It will be a documentation maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 5):

Javadoc is intended to document the API, *not* the implementation.  You should avoid specifying implementation details in the Javadoc, because doing so limits your ability to change the implementation.  Callers might begin to depend on the implementation details that you've documented.

Use Javadoc to document the proper use of a class or method, especially things that are not self-documenting, such as preconditions, postconditions, side effects, and exceptions, including runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any option to mention the lines in javadoc. The main reason behind this is as one can not see the code so if you mention lines in the javadoc, it doesn't make sense from documentation unless you can see the code.

For such line level references, better go with inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc and inline comments are not mutually exclusive. Javadoc the method then add inline comments in the method wherever you feel it's needed. You typically don't reference specific lines in a method's javadocs.